# CF7 Autoresponder (mail2) Delay Send

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

**Context**
I'm trying to delay sending the autoresponder (mail2) in contact form 7 for 8hours after the submission of the initial form. I'm thinking something like this:

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");  function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {
// get the contact form object
$wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

// if you wanna check the ID of the Form $wpcf->id

if (/*Perform check here*/) {
    // If you want to skip mailing the data, you can do it...  
    $wpcf->skip_mail = true;    
}

return $wpcf; }
```

**Problem** 
Not sure what filter/hooks to use.